# JLabel Width Not Working

Tags: java, fonts, jpanel, width, jlabel

I've set my JLabel's width to the width of a string, but when I do that, the JLabel cuts off the string in the middle, using ..., so instead of being "Ask me a question!", it ends up being "Ask me a question...". This could be a problem with the font I'm using, but I'm not sure. Any help?

Here's my custom JLabel class called BLANKJLabel:

```
package BLANK.BLANK.menufeatures;

import BLANK.BLANK.main.QnABotJPanel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class BLANKJLabel extends JLabel {

    public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);

    public BLANKJLabel(ImageIcon icon, String text, int x, int y) {
        int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
        int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

        this.setText(text);
        this.setFont(BLANKJPanel.font);
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        this.setIcon(icon);
        this.setSize(stringWidth, stringHeight);
    }

    public BLANKLabel(String text, int x, int y) {
        int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
        int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

        Dimension d = new Dimension(this.getPreferredSize());

        this.setText(text);
        this.setFont(BLANKJLabel.font);
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        this.setSize(d);
    }

}
```

Here's the class that uses it, BLANKJPanel:

```
package BLANK.BLANK.main;

import BLANK.BLANK.menufeatures.BLANKButton;
import BLANK.BLANK.menufeatures.BLANKJLabel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class QnABotJPanel extends JPanel {

    public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);

    static QnABotButton submitButton;
    static QnABotJLabel askMeAQuestionLabel;

    public static Font font = new Font("Avenir Next", Font.PLAIN, 20);

    String askMeAQuestion = "Ask me a question!";

    int askMeAQuestionWidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
    int askMeAQuestionHeight = (int)(font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

    public QnABotJPanel() {
        setLayout(new GroupLayout(this));

        submitButton = new QnABotButton("Submit", "/submit", QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 2 - 100, (QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 4) * 3 - 50);

        askMeAQuestionLabel = new QnABotJLabel(askMeAQuestion, QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 4 - askMeAQuestionWidth / 2, QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 3 - askMeAQuestionHeight / 2);

        this.add(submitButton);
        this.add(askMeAQuestionLabel);

        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (QnABotJPanel.submitButton.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {

                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        submitButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are using setLocation and setSize and not letting the layout managers to do there job?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because the LayoutManager might not do what I want. I want them in specific places and the LayoutManager might not put them there.

Comment: Try using getPreferredSize after you've set the text and font, but you may have issues with variable width fonts

Comment: @MadProgrammer But then I have to set a specific size...

Comment: You have to specify the size any way, `getPreferredSize` will provide you with what the `JLabel` thinks it wants automatically

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, I should use `this.getWidth` and `this.getHeight`? Because that's not working at all. JLabel doesn't even have a `getPreferredSize` method.

Comment: No, the width and height are set by the layout manager which uses the preferred/minimum/maximum size to make determinations about how best it should layout the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I get those values though?

Comment: As said, call getPreferredSize ... But, as I also said, of you're using a variable width font, you may have issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I call `getPreferredSize()`? Also, this font was present in Java, it's not external. Shouldn't it automatically be fixing itself?

Comment: Why? What gurantee do you have that any font is fixed or variable width, Java doesn't have it's own font format, it's just using the system fonts (TFT or what ever). getPreferredSize a method that's available to any component that extends from Component, so it's available to any Swing component as well...

Comment: @MadProgrammer It doesn't let me reference `getPreferredSize()` from the constructor because somehow my constructor is static and `getPreferredSize()` isn't. This seems like a serious liability because that means I have to specify `BLANKLabel.size()` every time.

Comment: According to your code, the constructors aren't static...

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I try to implement the `getPreferredSize()` inside `setSize()`, it tells me "Non-static method 'getPreferredSize' cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: No, no, no don't do it inside setSize. Call this.getPreferredSize() inside your constructor and pass the result to this.setSize

Comment: @MadProgrammer It doesn't appear at all when I do that. Also I fixed my code in the OP.

Comment: Based on your code, you asking for the preferredSize of the label BEFORE you've set the text or font, this information is required in order for the method to make decisions about what size it might like to be...

Answer (score 1):

My first piece of advice to you is to avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.

The next problem you are probably having is trying to perform an operation which the label is already capable of doing, calculating it's preferred size.

If you use `JLabel#getPreferredSize` AFTER you have set the text and font, it will tell you what it things is the size of the component should probably be.  This is what the layout manager API does by default

[image: Without layout manager]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new QnABotJPanel());
                frame.setSize(200, 50);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class QnABotJPanel extends JPanel {

//      public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
//      public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);

//      static QnABotButton submitButton;
//      static QnABotJLabel askMeAQuestionLabel;

        public static Font font = new Font("Avenir Next", Font.PLAIN, 20);

//      String askMeAQuestion = "Ask me a question!";
//
//      int askMeAQuestionWidth = (int) (font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//      int askMeAQuestionHeight = (int) (font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

        public QnABotJPanel() {
            setLayout(null);

            add(new BLANKJLabel("This is a banana", 0, 0));

//          submitButton = new QnABotButton("Submit", "/submit", QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 2 - 100, (QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 4) * 3 - 50);
//
//          askMeAQuestionLabel = new QnABotJLabel(askMeAQuestion, QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 4 - askMeAQuestionWidth / 2, QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 3 - askMeAQuestionHeight / 2);
//
//          this.add(submitButton);
//          this.add(askMeAQuestionLabel);
//
//          this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//
//              @Override
//              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                  if (QnABotJPanel.submitButton.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
//
//                  }
//              }
//
//          });
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
//          submitButton.addActionListener(listener);
        }

    }

    public static class BLANKJLabel extends JLabel {

//      public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
//      public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);
        public BLANKJLabel(ImageIcon icon, String text, int x, int y) {
//          int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//          int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

            this.setText(text);
            this.setFont(QnABotJPanel.font);
            this.setLocation(x, y);
            this.setIcon(icon);
            this.setSize(getPreferredSize());
        }

        public BLANKJLabel(String text, int x, int y) {
//          int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//          int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

            this.setText(text);
            this.setFont(QnABotJPanel.font);
            this.setLocation(x, y);
            this.setSize(getPreferredSize());
        }

    }
}
```

And making use of the layout management API...

[image: With layout manager]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new QnABotJPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class QnABotJPanel extends JPanel {

//      public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
//      public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);

//      static QnABotButton submitButton;
//      static QnABotJLabel askMeAQuestionLabel;

        public static Font font = new Font("Avenir Next", Font.PLAIN, 20);

//      String askMeAQuestion = "Ask me a question!";
//
//      int askMeAQuestionWidth = (int) (font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//      int askMeAQuestionHeight = (int) (font.getStringBounds(askMeAQuestion, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

        public QnABotJPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(new BLANKJLabel("This is a banana"));

//          submitButton = new QnABotButton("Submit", "/submit", QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 2 - 100, (QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 4) * 3 - 50);
//
//          askMeAQuestionLabel = new QnABotJLabel(askMeAQuestion, QnABotWindow.windowWidth / 4 - askMeAQuestionWidth / 2, QnABotWindow.windowHeight / 3 - askMeAQuestionHeight / 2);
//
//          this.add(submitButton);
//          this.add(askMeAQuestionLabel);
//
//          this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//
//              @Override
//              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                  if (QnABotJPanel.submitButton.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
//
//                  }
//              }
//
//          });
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
//          submitButton.addActionListener(listener);
        }

    }

    public static class BLANKJLabel extends JLabel {

//      public AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
//      public FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(affineTransform, true, true);
        public BLANKJLabel(ImageIcon icon, String text) {
//          int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//          int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

            this.setText(text);
            this.setFont(QnABotJPanel.font);
            this.setIcon(icon);
        }

        public BLANKJLabel(String text) {
//          int stringWidth = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getWidth());
//          int stringHeight = (int) (QnABotJPanel.font.getStringBounds(text, fontRenderContext).getHeight());

            this.setText(text);
            this.setFont(QnABotJPanel.font);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! Although, as you can see I do make use of `GroupLayout` so I don't really know what you're talking about.

Comment: Then why pass the x/y position? Why set the size? The GroupLayout would take care of it automatically

Comment: Also, GroupLayout is a pain in the butt, it's best used with form editors

Comment: Well, if it was designed to be messed with that way than it's fine isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can manipulate JLabel (in this example it is applied in a JPopupMenu)

```
JLabel labelPop = new JLabel("Options de la table", JLabel.CENTER); //  JLabel with centered text
labelPop.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10000, 0));                   // Determine the width
labelPop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));                    // Determine the height
labelPop.setOpaque(true);                                           // Set transparency 
labelPop.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 51));                        // Apply the background color
labelPop.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));                    // Apply the text color
```

Answer (score -1):

Increase the size of stringWidth by adding a constant.